# jQuery mobile: Pinch/Zoom/Scale Gesture - console.log('something');

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, pinch

I simply can't find anything in the docs or anywhere on how to detect a simple pinch-zoom Gesture on a touchdevice with jQuery Mobile? I would also considering using another library or anything. I just want to detect if the user is trying to scale the content on the website.

So I don't need to handle a pinch gesture on an element of the site but on the site itself. I just want to listen for a pinch gesture on my website.

Any idea how to do that?

thank you

Comment: Here is an also helpful answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183174/simplest-way-to-detect-a-pinch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vendor support varies and iOS the only platform whereto use multi-touch Javascript events reliably.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW8

From Apple's own documentation.

Comment: Do we have some touch events for jQuery mobile which run on Android as well??

Comment: The vendor support varies and iOS the only platform whereto use multi-touch Javascript events reliably.