# Detect pinch to zoom when 'user-scalable' is set to yes

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, hammer.js, jquery-events

How can I detect the scale (or distance pinched) of the pinch to zoom when the `meta name="viewport"` is set to `user-scalable=yes`?

I've tested on Android but the pinch to zoom can't be detected if the `meta name="viewport"` is set to `user-scalable=yes`. If the `meta name="viewport"` is set to `user-scalable=no` then the pinch to zoom can be detected but then I'm not able to zoom in on the document.

Here are my tests on jsFiddle:

Hammer.js:
http://jsfiddle.net/pE42S/

```
var pziW = "test";
var viewport_width = $(window).innerWidth();
var zoom = 0;

var hammer = new Hammer(document.getElementById("touchme"));

hammer.ontransformstart = function(ev) {
    console.log("ontransformstart");
    console.log(ev);
    //pziW = $(window).innerWidth() / 2 * ev.scale;
    zoom = ev.scale;
    var msg = "ontransformstart " + pziW + " scale " + zoom;
    log(msg);
};
hammer.ontransform = function(ev) {
    console.log("ontransform");
    console.log(ev);
    zoom -= ev.scale;
    viewport_width+=viewport_width*zoom;
    zoom = ev.scale;
    pziW=viewport_width;
    //pziW = $(window).innerWidth() / 2 * ev.scale;
    jqUpdateSize();
    var msg = "ontransform " + pziW + " scale " + zoom;
    log(msg);
};
hammer.ontransformend = function(ev) {
    console.log("ontransformend");
    console.log(ev);
    var msg = "ontransformend " + pziW + " scale " + zoom;
    log(msg);
};
```

TouchSwipe:
http://jsfiddle.net/pE42S/1/

```
$(function() {      
    $("#touchme").swipe( {
        pinchStatus:function(event, phase, direction, distance , duration , fingerCount, pinchZoom) {
            console.log("pinchStatus");
            console.log(event);
            pziW=viewport_width - distance;
            $("#log").text(pziW);
            jqUpdateSize();
        },
        fingers:2,  
        pinchThreshold:0  
    });
});
```

Somebody has an answer?

Comment: Have you looked at the jQuery plugin Touchy? [touchyjs.org](http://touchyjs.org/)

Comment: images doesn't work in jsfiddle. I can't check how it works right now. You mean native zoom doesn't work or 'pinch' zoom ?

Comment: I would refer to the answer to this StackOverflow question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183174/simplest-way-to-detect-a-pinch.

Comment: why this is not working for you : http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/Pinch_and_Swipe.html

Answer (score 3):

Now you can use Visual Viewport API for this (not for all browsers). Just check `window.visualViewport.scale > 1`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be with a generic touchstart handler:

- Wait until the user starts touching at least two points ( event.touches.length > 1)
- Note the x & y start coordinates for both touches, attach touchend listeners
- Wait until the touches end.
- Remove touchend listeners & measure distance.

Even easier would be using gesture events and the event.scale property, see the great answers at [Simplest way to detect a pinch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183174/simplest-way-to-detect-a-pinch) for more details.

Comment: Hey, you have explained the logic very well. But I wonder why we didn't use it, wouldn't we get results if we use ScreenX / Y coordinates instead of PageX / Y?