# Catching Mac trackpad zoom in OS X Safari

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, trackpad

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416851/catching-mac-trackpad-zoom) asks how to catch a trackpad two-fingers pinch-zoom on a Mac computer.

The accepted answer explains that Chrome for OS X triggers a `wheel` event with `ctrl` key pressed when detecting a two-fingers pinch on the trackpad.

Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work in Safari.

**How to detect a two-fingers pinch-zoom in OS X Safari with Javascript?**

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE : support has been added, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37183950/1054573

I have been looking exhaustively for a solution to this. Google maps fails to catch the pinch to zoom event in desktop Safari. So I really don't think it's currently possible.

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/a/37183950/1054573 ?

Comment: Excellent - great to know that's been added - thanks!